# Is that possible to group result on 3 months period basis?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to group results by 3 months period starting by the current month as shown below:

```
row1      15 -- This should contain November, September and October
row2      25 -- This should contain August, July and June
row3      5  -- This should contain May, April and March
row4      2  -- This is should contain February and Janvier
```

I have no idea about how to accomplish this. Any help please?

So far I can group by month:

```
SELECT MONTH(date), MONTHNAME(date) as month, COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(date) < NOW()  GROUP BY MONTH(date) ORDER BY MONTH(date) DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to check date by your scripting language of your every specific month

Comment: Looks like the word trimester is creating confusion so I just updated my question. Thanks

Comment: I’d try with a simple CASE that assigns a value to the months, f.e. 1 for November, September or October, 2 for June, July or August, etc. – and then group by that value.

Comment: Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909844/sql-how-to-group-in-time-periods

Comment: Doesn’t even have to be a long CASE statement, could be done using a single [ELT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) that “assigns” the appropriate grouping value for the given month …

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [PERIOD_DIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff) and some maths to find the records.

```
-- This line creates YYYYMM representation of today; you can use PHP instead
SET @T1 = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y%m');

SELECT MIN(`date`) AS `Range Start`, MAX(`date`) AS `Range End`, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY FLOOR(PERIOD_DIFF(@T1, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m')) / 3)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Sample output:

```
Range Start  Range End   Count
-----------  ----------  -----
2013-09-01   2013-11-26  87
2013-06-01   2013-08-31  92
2013-03-01   2013-05-31  92
2012-12-01   2013-02-28  90
2012-09-01   2012-11-30  91
```

`PERIOD_DIFF` returns the number of months between periods P1 and P2 (both arguments are strings in YYYYMM format).

In the above query we calculate the month difference for each row (e.g. NOV-2013 is 0, OCT-2013 is 1, SEP-2013 is 2, AUG-2013 is 3 and so on).

The difference divided by 3 plus `FLOOR` yields the quarter number (NOV-2013 is 0.00 -> 0, OCT-2013 is 0.33 -> 0, SEP-2013 is 0.66 -> 0, AUG-2013 is 1.00 -> 1, and so on).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work...

```
SELECT FLOOR((MONTH(date))/3)+1 quarter
     , COUNT(*) total FROM my_dates 
 GROUP 
    BY FLOOR((MONTH(date))/3);
```

Comment: It does not. You should use CEIL rather than FLOOR, in the group by, otherwise you will get a super weird "fifth quarter" on december. Moreover, you should probably group by year as well

Comment: @ma1069 Going for the archaeology badge?

Answer (score 1):

Updated query after @Strawberry solution.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(tradeDate, '%Y'), '-quarter-', CEIL((MONTH(date))/3)) quarter,
  COUNT(*) total FROM my_dates
GROUP BY
  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(tradeDate, '%Y'), '-quarter-', CEIL((MONTH(date))/3));
```