# SQL Server query Group By Trimester

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm finding a way to group SQL query by trimester. I have found a way to do it using MySQL on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20213910/19129790).

This is what I'm expecting:

```
Range Start  Range End   Count
-----------  ----------  -----
2013-09-01   2013-11-26  87
2013-06-01   2013-08-31  92
2013-03-01   2013-05-31  92
2012-12-01   2013-02-28  90
2012-09-01   2012-11-30  91
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT MIN(start_date) AS Range_Start, MAX(start_date) AS Range_End, COUNT(ID) AS Total
FROM [dbo].[table]
GROUP BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(start_date)+1, start_date), DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(start_date)+1,getdate())) /3) 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

This is what I get:

```
Range Start             Range End               Count
-----------             ----------              -----
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 8
1952-01-01 00:00:00.000 1952-01-01 00:00:00.000 2
1954-01-01 00:00:00.000 1954-01-01 00:00:00.000 11
1955-01-01 00:00:00.000 1955-01-01 00:00:00.000 3
1956-01-01 00:00:00.000 1956-01-01 00:00:00.000 2
1957-01-01 00:00:00.000 1957-01-01 00:00:00.000 8
1958-01-01 00:00:00.000 1958-01-01 00:00:00.000 2
1959-01-01 00:00:00.000 1959-01-01 00:00:00.000 5
1960-01-01 00:00:00.000 1960-01-01 00:00:00.000 17
1960-03-17 00:00:00.000 1960-03-17 00:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your query? Please provide sample data and expected results as described by [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is the first table your original input or already the result of a query? Why not simply showing sample input and expected outcome? You are asking too complicated...

Comment: You need both sample (starting) data as well as your desired results, else we don't know what the query is supposed to do.